# Moodle database dump not working on restore

Tags: mariadb, moodle, collation

I was tryning to restore a MariaDB dump from a Moodle database, when I get this error:

```
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 10540: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

After a bit of research I targueted to the collation of the schema, which is utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

This error can be solve when I change the size from 255 to 170. However, sometimes it does not matter if it has 255 as size, because it create them.

Now,

1- Why is the dump file giving me this configuration if restoreing it does not work?

2- How is this working if the varchar size is not allowed?

3- There is any easier way to make this work, beside changin from 255 to 170?

Comment: What tool was used to create the dump? Is the collation of the database on the machine it was dumped on the same as the one you are trying to restore it to? Does the dump include the creation of the database or are you restoring only the data to a database that you've already created?

Comment: @Dave I am using  /bin/mysqldump -u User -p**** --routines $i  > "$dir/$i.$date.sql"

As a part of a script that dumps all the MySQL data. It only contains the data and tables. I am creating a new Schema in a new machine in order to test the backups

Comment: I identify 5 workarounds for that problem in [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes).

Comment: @RickJames I will give it a try to the last solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rick James says in an edit, the solution was the next steps:

```
   SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
   SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
   SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=1;
   logout & login (to get the global values);
   ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;  -- (or COMPRESSED)
```

In this case the steps were taken in order to reconfigure the database engine of the new server.